# The type or namespace name 'Animations' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When building the project, an error appears that "The type or namespace name 'Animations' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor'", but Visual Studio does not show errors and all the libraries are connected, I found a solution how to upload the dll file to the Plug-in but could not find where to download dll file UnityEditor. I want to use the Animator Controller in a unity editor.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor.Animations;

public class SkinSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;

    public AnimatorController skin1;
    public AnimatorController skin2;
    public AnimatorController skin3;
    public AnimatorController skin4;
    public AnimatorController skin5;
    public AnimatorController skin6;
    public AnimatorController skin7;
    public AnimatorController skin8;



    private void Start()
    {
        SetSkin(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SkinSelect"));
    }

    public void SetSkin(int ID)
    {
        switch (ID)
        {
            case 1:
                anim.runtimeAnimatorController = skin1;
                break;
            case 2:
                anim.runtimeAnimatorController = skin2;
                break;
            case 3:
                anim.runtimeAnimatorController = skin3;
                break;
            case 4:
                anim.runtimeAnimatorController = skin4;
                break;
            case 5:
                anim.runtimeAnimatorController = skin5;
                break;
            case 6:
                anim.runtimeAnimatorController = skin6;
                break;
            case 7:
                anim.runtimeAnimatorController = skin7;
                break;
            case 8:
                anim.runtimeAnimatorController = skin8;
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `UnityEditor` is a namespace specific for Unity Editor internal stuff and custom editor scripts ... it is not available in a build so you don't want to use anything from it in a `MonoBehaviour`!

Comment: Ok, and how do I fix it, I need to put the AnimatorController in an array

Comment: erase using UnityEditor.Animations;

Comment: Every script using UnityEditor should be inside Editor folder, is your case?

Comment: And in which folder Editor there are a lot of them, and which script ?

Comment: @Lotan that's recommended but not necessary ... you can also exclude them from the build using `#if UNITY_EDITOR` ...

Comment: @LehaJublin could you post a complete script? As said currently it makes no sense as you don't want this to be a `MonoBehaviour` ..

Comment: @derHugo Ok no problem , Done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned you do not want to use anything related to `UnityEditor` in your `MonoBehaviour` at least not in code that shall be executed in your app later.

It is only used to implement some special behaviors while working within the Unity Editor, mostly for custom Inspectors.

This namespace is completely stripped of during the build. So you will get compiler errors when building.

---

You should make your fields rather of type [`RuntimeAnimatorController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeAnimatorController.html)

```
public RuntimeAnimatorController skin1;
...
```

and remove any `using` statement that contains `UnityEditor` from your script.